# ? button functionality for another button

Tags: c++, qt

I have made peace with the fact that I cannot have both help button and minimize button at the same time, i want to implement the `?` button functionality to another button.
[image]

I want this button functionality(QWhatsThis) in `Help` button(shown above):
[image]

I want to try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039056/qt-qmainwindow-with-a-close-minimize-and-help-button) but not sure how to implement and [even this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140090/add-help-button-but-keep-maximize-and-minimize).

Comment: why not a `help` menu with `about` menu item in it?

Comment: I need QWhatsThis functionality in this button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [QWhatsThis](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qwhatsthis.html)

You can use the `QWhatsThis::createAction()` method that 'Returns a ready-made QAction, used to invoke "What's This?" context help'. You can put the returned action in your "About" menu

If you have already you own action, you can create a slot that calls `QWhatsThis::enterWhatsThisMode()`

```
void onHelpTriggered()
{
    QWhatsThis::enterWhatsThisMode();
}
```

Comment: I cannot use QWhatsThis and minimize together, i need to use either of one of those.

Comment: Sorry maybe I don't understand your question. I've understood that you want an action (the "Help" action in the picture) in your "About" menu with the What's this functionality. This works even if you have a minimize button in your window frame

Comment: OK, sorry you totally misunderstood the question. check the main post again, I have explained it better.

Comment: I want "?" button(beside close button) functionlatiy in the "help" button(tool bar)

Comment: I think I have undestood right. I have edited the answer with a second way to do the same thing